How do I change / edit / alter / modify keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu? Specifically, <Shift>+<Del> cuts to clipboard when I want to delete
This same basic question was asked before, to no avail:
How can I disable Shift + Delete as a shortcut for "Cut"?
I would have thought this would have been included in Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts.  However, nothing like Cut / Paste / &c is even listed. There's an option to ADD behavior, but I want to disable existing behavior that isn't in that menu.
I am fine if I have to change it per-program. But I do not know how, or where to look. I can't even tell where to start, since the solution isn't in what appears to be the labeled-for-this-exact-purpose space.
All the "answers" I find are about managing the clipboard, which is not at all what I want to do. I want to not lose my train of thought in the first place because of an accidental keystroke that +Z doesn't fix.
